# VueJs + TypeScript + Splitpanes import errors

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types

I have a VueJS view originally written in JavaScript and using the component "splitpanes" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/splitpanes). It was working fine and looked like this:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <Splitpanes :dbl-click-splitter="false" :horizontal="horizontal">
   <Pane id="pane-video" class="d-flex flex-column">
    ...
   </Pane>
  </Splitpanes>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import { Splitpanes, Pane } from "splitpanes";
import "splitpanes/dist/splitpanes.css";
export default Vue.extend({
  components: {
    Splitpanes,
    Pane
  },
...
</script>
```

I changed the code to TypeScript:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from "vue-class-component";
import Splitpanes from "splitpanes";
import Pane from "splitpanes";
@Component({
  components: { Splitpanes, Pane }
})
export default class VideoConf extends Vue {
```

After that I got this error (in VS Code):

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'splitpanes'. 'client-vue/node_modules/splitpanes/dist/splitpanes.common.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try `npm install @types/splitpanes` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'splitpanes';`Vetur(7016)

I tried both: `npm install @types/splitpanes` and alternatively I created a shims-splitpanes.d.ts file with "declare module 'splitpanes'". In both cases, the syntax checking error goes away (in  VS Code) and I can execute npm run serve, but when I open the page in the browser I get:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. (and the same error for Pane).

If I hover over this "splitpanes" on he line:

```
import Splitpanes from "splitpanes";
```

I can see how it points to the @types folder in node_modules:

module "/Users/lisandro/tmp/aws-chime/client-vue/node_modules/@types/splitpanes/index"

But I'm missing something and I don't know what it is. Perhaps this is due to my lack of understanding on how @types work and how they should be used in a TypeScript project?

Any ideas would be highly appreciated. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve my errors by removing `@types/splitpanes` and using the following type declaration instead (with the latest `splitpanes package`).

`splitpanes.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'splitpanes' {
    let Splitpanes : any;
    let Pane : any;

    export { Splitpanes, Pane }
}
```

Example `App.vue` (showing `v-model` working):

```
<template>
    <splitpanes class="default-theme">
        <pane min-size="25">
            <input type="text" v-model="text" />
        </pane>
        <pane min-size="35">
            <p>"{{ text }}"</p>
        </pane>
    </splitpanes>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { Splitpanes, Pane } from 'splitpanes';
import 'splitpanes/dist/splitpanes.css';

@Component({
    components: {
        Splitpanes,
        Pane
    }
})
export default class App extends Vue {
    text : string = "";
}
</script>

<style>
.splitpanes {
    height: 5em;
}
.splitpanes__pane {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

I'll also put a minimal `tsconfig.json` here (modified from the [Vue.js docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html)):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "strict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    }
}
```

Comment: I voted your answer but it does not show because my reputation is below 15. I'm already trying your solution but I'm going to wait to see if you can fix the issue with v-model and                 be so kind to share it. Thanks !!!

Comment: @lolmedo It seems my last answer basically ended up being a dead end (sorry about that), so I've edited my answer with the new solution.

Comment: Thanks again. Your latest solution worked like a charm !!! I still cannot vote but I wanted to thank you anyways.